# group filtering t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I've structure like below:

```
cid status

 1    T
 2    T
 1    T
 1    T
 2    T
 3    X
 3    T
 5    T
```

How to get `cid` where **all** statuses are 'T'.

Response must be(note that 3 is omitted since it has also a `X` status):

```
cid
 1
 2
 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a common table expression with a `ROW_NUMBER` function which is similar to `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT CID, RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY CID)
   FROM tbl
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT NULL FROM tbl t2
     WHERE t2.CID=tbl.CID
     AND Status <> 'T'
   )
)
SELECT CID FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bed7/5/0